# why does the code shows nothing when i run it

Tags: python

I was trying to make a lottery generating machine that checks how many tries it takes to get that winning ticket

```
from random import choice

pack = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'a','b','c','d','e')


my_ticket=[]
times = -1

robot_ticket = []
while len(robot_ticket) < 5:
    robo = choice(pack)
    robot_ticket.append(robo)
    continue

while robot_ticket == my_ticket:
    if robot_ticket not in my_ticket:
        times=times+1
        my_ticket.clear()
        while len(my_ticket) < 5:
            robo = choice(pack)
            my_ticket.append(robo)

    elif robot_ticket in my_ticket:
        print(f"total nuber of tries: {times}")
```

this program was the task of eric matthens book
ie, 9.15

Comment: `while robot_ticket == my_ticket:` this condition never met

Answer (score 0):

```
while robot_ticket == my_ticket
```

This condition will never be true because my_ticket is an empty array and it is getting compared with robot_ticket which has 5 random values.